# Add RESPONSIVE Videos to a Modal with FIXED Header / Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a Fixed header, and Fixed footer text modal, as well as a Fixed header, and Fixed footer video modal.  I Tested making videos Responsive.  However, the the bottom of responsive videos ends up going under the modal footer.  So, currently I Don't have the video modal responsive.  How can I get videos to display Responsive Without the fixed modal footer covering part of iFrame videos?!  Thanks!

```js
// Open A Modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get A Button That Opens A Modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-open-buttons");

// Get A <span> Element That Closes A Modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When User Clicks A Modal Open Button, Open A Modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}
// When Users click On A Modal Close Button <span> (x), Close A Modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
// When Users Click Anywhere Outside of a Modal, Close That Modal
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (Background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden By Default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay In Place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit On Top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full Width */
    height: 100%; /* Full Height */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Enable Scroll If Feeded */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(65,105,225,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(65,105,225,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.modal-open-buttons {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #4169E1;
  border-color: #663399;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The Close Button */
.modal-header .close {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #663399;
}

.modal-header .close:hover,
.modal-header .close:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  color: #4169E1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-header .left-column {
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.modal-header .right-column {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.modal-body {
    /* DON'T USE WIDTH FOR THE MODAL BODY!*/
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   color: #663399;
   padding-right: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
}

.modal-footer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #663399;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- The Above 3 Meta Tags MUST Come First In The Head; Any Other Head Content MUST Come AFTER These Tags -->
    
<Title>MODALS</Title>

</head>

<body>
    
<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Text Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-01" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
                
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A TEXT MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>

  <div class="columns right-column">

    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body">
        
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Video Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-02" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
                
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>

  <div class="columns right-column">

    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body">
      
      <p>VIDEO IS RESIZEABLE</p>
      
      <iframe width="300px" height="169px" src="https://NewTube.app/embed/ATrboWO" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by video is not responsive. From the question I can see one issue that you are facing is that the footer comes over the modal. Is there any other issue also?

Comment: A K T:  From what you wrote, it looks like I need to get the Fixed footer to Not go over the modal body.  How can I change that with the footer still being Fixed?  :--)

Comment: I Removed the Responsive coding until I can figure out how to have it Not be partly Under the modal footer.  :--)

Comment: the reason why the footer is coming over the modal body is the z-index of the footer, changing the z-index of modal footer and body will make the body appear in front but will create other problems like when the body is text not a video. I think the better way to go is to use a sticky footer rather than a fixed footer, that will push the footer down if the view window is small and if the window is large enough then it will stick to the bottom.

Comment: A K T:  I'm keeping a Fixed footer.  Sticky Isn't compatible with i/Apple products.  :--)

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit of your css first to make a good functional full screen modal, basically leave your header and footer as it is at top and bottom, while make the modal-content always in the middle with as much height as possible left with the `height: calc(100vh - 137px);` (137px is the total height of your current header and footer, you may change that later depend on your style...)

Now to your main question: a responsive video. From your code i'm not sure if you need full width video or just a small one like the code above, but the solution is the same: wrap your iframe in two div and the iframe with `position: absolute`, then calculate the video ratio you want:

```
div.iframe-outer-most {
    width: 300px; /* Change to whichever you need */
}
div.iframe-parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 75%; /* Ratio 4:3 (56.25% for 16:9 or custom calculator) */
}
div.iframe-parent iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

```js
// Open A Modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get A Button That Opens A Modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-open-buttons");

// Get A <span> Element That Closes A Modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When User Clicks A Modal Open Button, Open A Modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}
// When Users click On A Modal Close Button <span> (x), Close A Modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
// When Users Click Anywhere Outside of a Modal, Close That Modal
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (Background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden By Default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay In Place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit On Top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full Width */
  height: 100%; /* Full Height */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }

  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }

  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.modal-open-buttons {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #4169E1;
  border-color: #663399;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The Close Button */
.modal-header .close {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #663399;
}

.modal-header .close:hover,
.modal-header .close:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  box-sizing1: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  color: #4169E1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-header .left-column {
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.modal-header .right-column {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.modal-body {
  /* DON'T USE WIDTH FOR THE MODAL BODY!*/
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #663399;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 137px);
  margin-top: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-footer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  color: #4169E1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

div.iframe-outer-most {
  width: 300px; /* Change to whichever you need */
}

div.iframe-parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 75%; /* Ratio 4:3 (56.25% for 16:9 or custom calculator) */
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.iframe-parent iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Text Modal</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-01" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="columns left-column">
        <p>THIS IS A TEXT MODAL HEADER</p>
      </div>
      <div class="columns right-column">
        <span class="close">(X)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER! &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Video Modal</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-02" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="columns left-column">
        <p>THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER</p>
      </div>
      <div class="columns right-column">
        <span class="close">(X)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>VIDEO IS RESIZEABLE</p>
      <div class="iframe-outer-most">
        <div class="iframe-parent">
          <iframe src="https://NewTube.app/embed/ATrboWO" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Henry V:  I tested with your changes, and Didn't seem to get anywhere.  I need some Sleep.  :--)

Comment: Henry V: I'm still up! I Added to the CSS 500 by 82, as well as (@media only) max-width 600, and max-width 400 CSS, and I like it. :--)